# Proper time for a relativistic particle in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

It is an often cited fact that a muon falling through the atmosphere at great speed has a decay time longer than the one we would observe in the same particle at rest due to relativistic effects, and for this reason can reach the surface. That much is clear to me, as it's a basic effect of time dilation. In the frame of reference *of the muon*, only the usual $\sim2\,\mu s$ have passed.

However what puzzles me is the interaction of this phenomenon with relativistic quantum mechanics. To lay out two different cases:

1. consider a wavepacket describing a muon free falling through the atmosphere with an expectation value of its speed of around 0.95c. The muon will experience time dilation, but the wavepacket will not have one *sharp* value of momentum - rather, it will have an average expectation value, and a probability distribution over momenta. What is the lifetime observed? Is it the one determined by the average expectation value? Or is it rather a distribution of lifetimes, corresponding to the distribution of momenta?
2. consider now a negative muon tightly bound to a heavy nucleus. I know in this case muons tend to have shorter lifetimes due to their interactions with the nuclei themselves, but if that wasn't the case, would the muon's lifetime be altered? After all, it possesses a great deal of kinetic energy to balance out the low potential energy of its state. In a classical description, it would be 'orbiting' really fast and be subject to very large centripetal accelerations, which ought to make it experience time dilation. However in the quantum description it is not really orbiting at all, and the atom is at rest with respect to me. So what happens?

I imagine QFT has answers to both these questions, so I'm curious to know what is it. Also, are these answers also attainable with a simple Dirac equation approach, or is that disregarding some key physics that make it impossible to use in this case (for example, since it does not describe the muon's decay)?

Comment: In reality, the muon is in  a state which is close to the coherent state — the uncertainty principle is saturated. Try calculating the uncertainty in time dilation and compare it to the absolute value.

Comment: I realise well that in practice in cosmic rays the effect is tiny. But tiny isn't the same as non-existent. "I can't measure it" is one thing, but if I could, what would I measure?

Comment: well in reality there isn’t such a thing as “one muon”, it’s all quantum field theory, which is also likely incomplete.

Comment: That still feels like an unsatisfactory answer to me though. Sure, if you go down enough, you get QFT, but then does that mean that a simple Dirac equation can *not* describe something as the proper time experienced by a particle? And if not, if I did the QFT calculation, what would it predict?

Comment: You’re considering muon decay which is a QFT interaction so no the free Dirac equation can’t describe it unless you add ad-hoc constraints which are equivalent to the first few orders of the perturbative expansion in the QFT. QFT prediction entirely depends on the shape of the muon state, so it isn’t an interesting thing to compute from the experimentalist’s point of view.

Comment: You're asking at least three questions. 1) Distribution of lifetimes
2) Lifetime of a bound muon 3) Dirac equation or QFT?
I can't give you a true answer, that's why I'm writing a comment.
Undoubtedly the QFT approach is the really satisfactory one, but a
simplified approach could also be possibile. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Also, a muon (in its rest frame) doesn't have a fixed lifespan, it has a mean lifetime, which is inherently probabilistic. The mean lifetime times ln(2) is the half-life.

Comment: @Okarin Remember that a muon "at rest" doesn't have a sharp value of momentum, either.

Comment: @PM2Ring sure, but if I prepared a bunch of muons in the same exact momentum state (I know it's impossible, thought experiment), their *distribution* of decay times would be known and exponential. If instead there was a distribution on momenta (and dilations) as well, it'd be a convolution with some weirder shape.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly of course, but realistically, its distribution of momenta will be entirely within values far smaller than the ones for which the relativistic gamma would cause noticeable time dilation.

Comment: Ok, what you said in those last two comments is fair enough.

Comment: @Okarin Right, but if the "at rest" distribution is narrow enough to neglect time dilation, then won't the the highly-boosted distribution also be narrow enough neglect the _differences_ in time dilation of the different momenta in the boosted distribution?

Comment: In practice, yes, at least in cosmic rays. But my question is, in theory, what would I observe? An exponential distribution that depends on the gamma factor connected to the expectation value of the momentum, or a convolved distribution that accounts for the whole momentum probability distribution?